# When clicking first button,it becomes highlighted and while clicking second,second highlighted and first become normal

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am creating an app,which contains five buttons ,created programmatically.The following are the requirements...

while clicking the first button it stay highlighted.while clicking second button ,first become normal and second stays highlighted...ie the particular button clicked becomes highlighted ,all others remains normal.......please help..

Comment: Please show your code. Stackoverflow is a site to help you solve issues with your code, not write it for you

Comment: You have got 3 answers for your question, so you should "accept" one of these answers by clicking on the check mark! (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). - For follow-up problems, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalbackgroundimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //not highlighted
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightedbackgroundimage"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected]; //highlighted
```

and now when you set your `button.selected = YES` it will get highlighted

so you could do something like this on button click

```
button1.selected = YES;
otherButton.selected = NO;
```

#### EDIT

Simple solution to your problem would be to create one ibaction connect it to all your buttons you want to selected/deselect and just do this

```
-(IBAction)someButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender{
    button1.selected = NO;
    button2.selected = NO;
    button3.selected = NO; //and so on...just set all your buttons to selected = NO

    //at the end you just select button you clicked
    sender.selected = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution to this:

Get a property to keep track of the selected button

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIBUtton *lastSelectedButton;
```

In your button callback method (the selector you configured when you added the buttons):

```
- (void)didClickButton:(UIButton *)button {
    if (self.lastSelectedButton isEqual:button) {
        // Don't need to do anything in this case because the button is already selected
        return;
    }
    [self.lastSelectedButton setSelected:NO];
    [button setSelected:YES];
    [self setLastSelectedButton:button];
}
```

Let me know if you have questions or need more help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a instance variable `int` which holds a tag value. Now which ever button you click you need to clear the previous button's tag value and assign it to the current button.

For Ex:

```
int const TAG_HIGHLIGHTED_BUTTON = 100;

- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)button {
    UIButton *prevButton = [self.view viewWithTag:TAG_HIGHLIGHTED_BUTTON];
    [prevButton setTag:0];

    [button setTag:TAG_HIGHLIGHTED_BUTTON];
}
```